# MongoDB is not registering as service in services.msc

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have tried to install and uninstall 3-4 times to identify my problems. Every time after successful installation of mongoDB, it stops service and gets me an error when I try to connect from the local server[connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017] and I get a message from windows [windows security alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z60JP.png) after this setting, MongoDB is removed from services.msc. I have checked both options one by one and also checked both of these from the control panel but still every time my problem is same.

Update: **I have tried to set path also as variable**.

Comment: How did you install the service?

Comment: I have followed my instructor and installed MongoDB Community sever 5.0.5 version.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. I asked "how" did you install it, not "why". You can install/remove service also with option, see [mongod.exe](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/)

Comment: First I have downloaded mongoDB Community sever installer ".msi". Then I clicked on the installer and follow the displayed interface and go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

The .msi does not work so well. Better create a config file like this

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\MongoDB\data\mongod

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\MongoDB\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true

processManagement:
  windowsService:
    serviceName: MongoDB
    displayName: MongoDB
    description: MongoDB Server - Standalone DB

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

and then install the service like this

```
mongod.exe --config "c:\MongoDB\config\mongod.cfg" --install
```

You need to run this command as Administrator. Then the service should start automatically at boot time.

Comment: In the example, you have used many terms which I am not getting as like processManagement, journal, logAppend etc. Please explain it.

Comment: See [Configuration File Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#configuration-file-options) - it explains every single entry.

Comment: What is the process of changing this config? I have tried to change mongod.cfg  `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin` that is already installed mongoDB and apply settings which are mentioned above, and then I again found error message when running this command `mongod.exe --config "c:\MongoDB\config\mongod.cfg" --install`.

**Error report:** mongod.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Comment: Add `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin` to your `PATH` or use `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin\mongod.exe` instead